# Reading files using java FTPClient

Tags: java, multithreading, ftp, bufferedreader, ftp-client

I am using FTPClient to do FTP on one of server. I am able to get all the list of the files but when I am tryto read those file it is showing "connection closed", "connection refused", "connection reset" exception. I am using following code for FTP

```
  FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
  client.connect("IpAddress");
  client.login("Username", "Password");
  client.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);
  client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
  FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles(dirPath);
```

above code is givng me all the file names then I passing these name in my search object. There I am using same "client" object

```
 InputStream in = client.retrieveFileStream("filename with path as a string");
 try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
       while (null != reader && (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (null != line && line.contains(wordToSearch)) {
              System.out.println("word Found");
            }
        }
```

that folder contains too many files. I am able to fetch all the files why is it failing when reading them.

Exception is :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
22:57:22,594  INFO Connector:38 - Traversing and Searching Finished......
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:894)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:759)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3293)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3271)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2930)
    at com.novigolabs.connectors.FtpConnector.listFiles(FtpConnector.java:44)
    at com.novigolabs.connectors.FtpConnector.listFiles(FtpConnector.java:55)
    at com.novigolabs.search.Traverse.initiateSearch(Traverse.java:117)
    at com.novigolabs.search.Traverse.run(Traverse.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Just in case it helps, please post exact exceptions with stack trace into your your question.

Comment: updated stack trace...

Comment: The exception you have posted links to the `listFiles` method which you say succeeds. Please post the code corresponding to the line 44 and 55 of your FtpConnector.java file...

Comment: 44 FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles(dirPath);
45 String word = search.getWordToSearch();...If I am commenting search code then it is working fine...I don know why is it failing when performing searching